# Latest Mean.IO not working on Windows

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, mean.io

Tried installing latest Mean.Io on 2 separate Windows machines, Windows 10 & 7 with the following commands:

```
 sudo npm install -g mean-cli 
$ mean init <myApp>
$ cd <myApp> && npm install
```

Both are running latest version of Node v4.4.4 and both have latest version of MongoDb installed.

After running npm update and attempting to run the mean app, it complains that Mongoose is not found, so in both instances had to manually do an npm install on Mongoose. Afterwards, when trying to start the app again, it shows that "MeanApp started on port 3000" however when opening localhost:3000 it just hangs there with no actual response or timeouts. It outputs "GET / - - - - ms "  in the terminal.

Any ideas as to why Mean.Io is not working on Windows?

Comment: Did you check your `npm install` logs? Did anything fail to install?